# After GRUB: display not working on Asus laptop

Tags: linux-mint, usb, dual-boot, graphics

I have a usb with Linux Mint 18 and elementary os installed via Rufus,
After selecting the usb as a primary boot device I encounter mint's GRUB.

Whatever option I pick hovever (mint, or compability mint) the result is the same: **display not working at all**.
I can clearly hear the mint intro screen sound, and amplifying the sound witha a shortcut works, so the system is clearly loaded correctly.

I have tried disabling `safety boot` but it did not do a thing.

The laptop specs are:

- Asus k501LX laptop
- Dedicated GTX 950m
- Windows 10 x64 as base system
- i7-6500U 2.5Ghz
- 250GB SSD Drive, brand and model not found

What could be the issue here and how could I solve it?

Using grub commands `nvidia/nouveau.modeset=0` did not solve the issue!

Comment: You could disable modesetting by appending `nouveau.modeset=0` to the kernel line when you boot.

Comment: Didn't work. Tried `nvidia.modeset=0` without luck eiter